# CSS Grid auto-height columns to content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout like this:

[image: Grid Layout]

I want the grid height to be according to the content. The pagination area height to be according to its box-sizing and the image area to take up the rest of the available space. I'm relatively new to grid. Help would be highly appreciated.

This is what I'm getting:

[image: This is what I'm getting]

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, min-content);
}
```

The problem is pagination and image sections takes half of the grid area. I do not want any section to have a fixed height in pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response to a previous awnser here i have tried to make the changes that are being looked for.

From what i can gather you are describing 3 total elements Image, Pagination, Content
of these 3 total elements you would like

- Content to occupy 100% of the width of the right side
- Pagination to live on the left side and occupy a small amount that is just enough to  fit the pagination
- Image to live on the left side an occupy the remaining space

To do this we can  still use grid we just need to specify different values for our template which I have done below. The key here is min-content

```css
html body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.your_main_class {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50vw 50vw;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "image cont"
                        "pagination cont";
}
 div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
 .image{ 
   grid-area: image; 
   background: red;
 }
 
 .pagination{ 
  grid-area: pagination; 
  background: blue;
 }
 
 .content{ 
   grid-area: cont; 
   background: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="your_main_class">
    <div class="image"> Image </div>
    <div class="pagination"> Pagination </div>
    <div class="content"> content </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by specifying the area of the divs. Check the snippet bellow.

```css
.your_main_class {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
   grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.image{ 
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 6; 
  background: red;
}

.pagination{ 
 grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 6; 
 background: blue;
}

.content{ 
  grid-area: 1 / 6 / 4 / 13; 
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="your_main_class">
  <div class="image"> </div>
  <div class="pagination"> </div>
  <div class="content"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with specifying grid area for pagination will take more space than it's box-sizing if the content is more. What I'm trying to achieve is no matter than the content the pagination should take up the space as per it's content and the rest available space should be for the image.